# Getting OCR text in Another line while using Pytesseract

Tags: python, image, python-tesseract

When I was trying `image_to_string` in Pytesseract the image has text in the same line, but the output has the same text in the different line.

Do i need to do any image processing before OCR?

[image: This Is the image I am using for OCR]

[image: This is the Output]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use extra config parameter psm. set the value to 6.

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang="eng", config="--psm 6")
```

Hope this helps!